# simple blog engine for website

Tags: .net, asp.net

I know that there's a lot of free open source blog engine out there such as BlogEngine.NET. However that's an overkill for my purpose... I so far has created my own simple one by storing posts in a .xml file and so every time the main page loads it reads from all those xml files and displays it as posts.

Now my problem is when a user clicks on a post title I want it to show on a new page(.aspx), so if the title is X then I want a new page called X.aspx when the user clicks on the title on the homepage. I hope this makes sense.

My question is how do I create such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you look at the code for [dasBlog](http://dasblog.codeplex.com/) as it has very similar behavior to this.

Comment: do you know which part I should look for?

Comment: You can get the code here: http://dasblog.codeplex.com/ 
I'm not sure where to look as I've not looked at the source in a long time, but I would start with the macros.cs in the web.core and the templates in the theme folders.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to pass a parameter in the link.

For example :
blog.aspx?title=blog%20title1

In blog.aspx, accept parameter "title" and show the specific blog entry only.

Comment: okay say I have the title hyperlinked to blog.aspx?title=blog%20title1
then how would I write the code to show the specific blog entry only?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a rewrite-engine like [UrlRewriter.net](http://urlrewriter.net/), that translates your url's from

> http://localhost/my-article-title.aspx

to

> http://localhost/posting.aspx?title=my-article-title

In your `Page_Init` of the posting.aspx page, load the title parameter, and look for the posting in your XML file with that title (f.e. using XPATH or LINQ2XML). Then display the needed information from the XML file.

Comment: I don't even have the my-article-title.aspx yet.. but I have a home page which has all the blog post inside a div tag... now what I want is that when a user clicks on the post title on the home page it will redirect to http://localhost/my-article-title.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party library called urlrewriter.net its available:

- http://urlrewriter.net/

You will need access to IIS (VPS or Dedicated hosting) if you want to implement extensionless urls (ie with the .aspx on the end).

I have written an article which explains how to set this up in a very clean way:

- http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2009/11/advanced-url-rewriting-for-rest-of-us.html

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I figured I'd share for future readers... check out "Nickel".  It's a super easy to use C#.NET blog engine.  It uses URL routing to produce short, clean URLs based on the page title.

http://nickel.codeplex.com/

This produces URLs like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/a-web-page-title
http://www.mysite.com/an-authors-name
http://www.mysite.com/a-tag
```

Where the "subdirectory" leads you to the appropriate article or articles.